# Using functions within a class

Tags: python, class

I wrote a class to wrap around some string manipulations methods as such:

```
class bstring(str):
    words2numbers = {
    '1' : 'one ',
    '2' : 'two ',
    '3' : 'three ',
    '4' : 'four ',
    '5' : 'five ',
    '6' : 'six ',
    '7' : 'seven ',
    '8' : 'eight ',
    '9' : 'nine ',
    '0' : 'zero '
    }

    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s

    def alpha_num(self):
        return ''.join(words2numbers[i] if i in words2numbers else i for i in self.s)

    def replace_punctuation(self):
        import string
        table = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})
        return self.s.translate(table)

    def norm_func(self):
        s = self.alpha_num()
        s = replace_punctuation(s)
        s = ' '.join(i for i in s.split())
        return s.lower()

    def encode_phonetic(self):
        return [i for i in norm_func()]
```

With the example test:

```
rand_string = '123 Josh Street, Ontoria, 675 Canada'

string = bstring(rand_string)

print(string.norm_func())
print(string.encode_phonetic())
```

The first `print` returns `one two three josh street ontoria six seven five canada`, which is as expected but the second print fails with `NameError: name 'norm_func' is not defined`.

I understand that calling functions from within a class requires the `self` instance but I am confused why it worked when I ran the first `print` function with calling the other 2 functions successfully, one of does not have `self`.

Given that fact that `norm_function` works, why doesn't `encode_phonetic` work?

*Traceback Error*

```
one two three josh street ontoria six seven five canada
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-440-ecf7dd4f18e5> in <module>()
      4 
      5 print(string.norm_func())
----> 6 print(string.encode_phonetic())

<ipython-input-437-23c9ae68fa2f> in encode_phonetic(self)
     31 
     32     def encode_phonetic(self):
---> 33         return [i for i in norm_func()]
```

**Further edits**

My bad, the kernal had the functions defined that lived in the global space and I was running them thinking it only lived in the local space. With the kernal restarted, the errors would be different. Giving as suggested, `words2numbered is not defined`.

Comment: This is rather chaotic, you define class `bstring` but create `f_string` object, define function `alpha_num` and call `alpha_numbers` then. Better you copy and paste the code directly.

Comment: Sorry I made some edits. I was too confused. Haha

Comment: I don't believe that this code as given would work as you describe.

Comment: @khelwood don't believe on what basis?

Comment: If `replace_punctuation` isn't additionally defined somewhere outside the class, a call to it without `self.` or similar just can't work. Maybe try a `print(dir())` in the test code outside the class to see if it is defined.

Comment: On the basis that it does not make sense as Python code. You would get `NameError: global name 'words2numbers' is not defined` the first time `alpha_num()` was called.

Comment: My bad, thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To refer to a method of an object, you need to specify the instance you're working on every time (unlike, say, Java). So `encode_phonetic` needs to be:

```
def encode_phonetic(self):
    return [i for i in self.norm_func()]
#                      ^^^^^
```

The same problem is present in a few of the defined methods too e.g. `norm_func` refers to `alpha_numbers` and `replace_punctuation` without the `self`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the `replace_punctuation` worked though I did not place `self`?

Comment: The only reference to a field has `self` before it i.e. `self.s.translate(table)`

Comment: @BernardL I don't think it should have worked, unless you have a global definition of the function.  Try calling it from outside the class - if there's another definition then that should work.

Comment: Yeah my bad, it failed. If you see the updated part, I confused myself when I declared the variable earlier (out of the example).